Should we delete the answers of off-topic question so the the question is going to be deleted?
We have a lot of off-topic questions. Considering that within almost a year and a half, I've 881 close votes and this doesn't count the duplicates that I've found and for that I can not cast a close vote.
After this recent question What type of encryption is this? [closed] I've noticed that before the consensus or the moderator can close a question some people can provide an answer and the answer can stay there as long as if the OP doesn't delete ( and that has some rules Why and how are some questions deleted?.
As we know, a closed question is automatically deleted some after time if there is no answer to this question otherwise that will stay there.
It is possible to cast a delete question vote before 48 hours. The number of active people who have the delete cast vote may not be enough for our community. Also the number of votes a bit problematic with the upvotes.
So my suggestions

Regardless of the answers, delete the off-topic questions if a flag is raised by a user.
Delete or ask to delete the answers so that the closed question will be deleted by the system.

Your consideration/suggestions?

Generally we should keep within the generic rules for SE. There is of course always the option to flag if you want anything deleted for a specific reason.

Personally I don't care much if a Q/A is deleted or not. It's unlikely to be found by using an internet / SE search. And if it is for a CTF or course then maybe they should update the questions once in a while (easier said than done maybe). If it is homework we should actively mention to the answerer that our policy is not to answer (hints in an extensive answer is a bit of an odd one out, possibly).

No.
There are specific and standardized rules on the SE network on how to deal with closed questions and their answers. We're not special enough to just ignore them.
If an answer has a positive score it should stay. After all somebody thought it was useful / helpful / interesting and there wasn't a group of people that actively disliked the answer enough to push the score to nonpositive again.
Indeed posts should mostly be deleted if they actively violate SE guidelines or are actively harmful. Answering a question that was later closed doesn't qualify. Deleting such an answer would punish a person that most likely acted in good faith to help another person out.
As for questions, if it wasn't upvoted the system will clean it up eventually and we don't drown in closed questions enough that we'd have to start deleting them to keep the active page clean.

Yo; we should delete the closed questions.

fill reasons.


No; we should not touch once the question is closed; since

fill reasons.

